# put column name as a value if meets certain conditions in R

Tags: r

Say I have a dataset from four observations, like this:

```
data <- data.frame(obs = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                   test1 = c(5, 3, 2, 99), 
                   test2 = c(2, 3, 99, 2),
                   test3 = c(4, 2, 5, 99))
```

Is there a way to create a fifth column called 'missing' that will display the column name for which the value in that row is 99? An example of the result I want here:

```
data_result <- data.frame(obs = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                          test1 = c(5, 3, 2, 99), 
                          test2 = c(2, 3, 99, 2),
                          test3 = c(4, 2, 5, 99), 
                          miss = c(NA, NA, "test2", "test1, test3" ))
> data_result
  obs test1 test2 test3         miss
1   a     5     2     4         <NA>
2   b     3     3     2         <NA>
3   c     2    99     5        test2
4   d    99     2    99 test1, test3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R base functions:

```
data$miss <- sapply(split(data, data$obs), function(x) {
   x <- paste0(names(x)[x==99], collapse=",");
   x[x==""]<-NA;
   x
  })
> data
  obs test1 test2 test3        miss
1   a     5     2     4         <NA>
2   b     3     3     2         <NA>
3   c     2    99     5       test2
4   d    99     2    99 test1,test3
```

Answer (score 1):

with datatable:

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(data)[,missing:=paste(names(data)[-1][.SD==99],collapse=","),by=obs][]
    obs test1 test2 test3     missing
1:   a     5     2     4            
2:   b     3     3     2            
3:   c     2    99     5       test2
4:   d    99     2    99 test1,test3
```

Comment: Or reshape, `melt(data, id="obs")[, .(mi = toString(variable[value == 99])), by=obs]`